# Ionic2 view doesn't bind with observable

Tags: data-binding, ionic2, components, observable

I have the following component class that receives an observable from a service. I want my component to unsubscribe when destroyed. This is the code is working and the view gets updated (the view renders different content depending on the value of state with *ngIf):

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'my-widget.component.html',
    selector: 'my-widget'
})
export class MyWidgetComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // Enum type variable to keep state
    state: MyWidgetStateType;

    // This is needed to be able to use the enum type in the template
    private myWidgetStateType = MyWidgetStateType;
    // Keep a reference to the observable to unsubscribe from it
    private sub: Subscriber<any>;

    constructor(public myWidgetService: MyWidgetService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = Subscriber.create((state: MyWidgetStateType) => {
            console.log('Widget state: ' + MyWidgetStateType[state]);
            this.state = state;
        });
        this.myWidgetService.getState().subscribe(this.sub);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe here
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

The state type is an enum with 3 states:

```
export enum MyWidgetStateType {
    Enabled,
    Dormant,
    Locked
};
```

And the view `my-widget.component.html`:

```
<h2>My Widget</h2>
<div *ngIf="state === myWidgetStateType.Enabled">
    <p>Enabled</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="state === myWidgetStateType.Dormant">
    <p>Dormant</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="state === myWidgetStateType.Locked">
    <p>Locked</p>
</div>
```

However, if I try to extract the call in the subscriber to a private function, the console.log method works but the view doesn't render any content according to the state (the `<h2>` title is rendered but there is no `<div>` element):

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'my-widget.component.html',
    selector: 'my-widget'
})
export class MyWidgetComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // Enum type variable to keep state
    state: MyWidgetStateType;

    // This is needed to be able to use the enum type in the template
    private myWidgetStateType = MyWidgetStateType;
    // Keep a reference to the observable to unsubscribe from it
    private sub: Subscriber<any>;

    constructor(public myWidgetService: MyWidgetService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = Subscriber.create(this.onStateChange);
        this.myWidgetService.getState().subscribe(this.sub);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe here
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    private onStateChange(state: MyWidgetStateType): void {
        console.log('Widget state: ' + MyWidgetStateType[state]);
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

The question is: why if the onStateChange function gets called, the view never gets the value update?

Of course this is not blocking my work because I have the solution above, but I'm just curious.